# GRUB menu not showing after installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS [Dual Boot]

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows, 22.04

I have installed `Windows 11` in SSD1 and then installed `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` in SSD2 but on restart I couldn't see `GRUB menu` which allows me to switch between Windows and Ubuntu.

I tried repairing boot configuration using Boot Repair tool.

```
$ boot-repair
```

[image]

But when I click "Recommended repair" option I am getting the below error.

[image]

I have used this tool earlier when I had Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10 in my PC and it worked fine, Does anyone have any idea about this error ?

Comment: You did not install Windows correctly. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drives since 2012. Legacy/BIOS mode was really for older systems. How you boot install media, it how it installs or repairs.

Comment: The problem is that your Windows is installed in 'Legacy-mode' and your Ubuntu in 'UEFI-mode'. Normally your Operating Systems have to be installed in the same mode. What you can try is open your UEFI (what some people still call BIOS) and change the setting from 'UEFI only' or 'Legacy only' to 'UEFI/Legacy'. Iḿ not sure though if this would solve the problem, or if your UEFI has this setting, since you don't menton what kind of hardware you have.

Comment: @oldfred I found the issue actually Ubuntu 22.04 was installed in UEFI mode and Windows 11 in Legacy mode

Comment: @HomerSimpson Yes exactly that was the issue, I reinstalled Windows 11 in UEFI mode then the problem got resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, actually in my PC Secure boot was Disabled hence when I was installing the Windows 11 I was getting the error message something like "This PC Doesn't Currently Meet All the System Requirements for Windows 11" so I watched some youtube videos which shows how to edit registry and bypass Secure boot & TPM check, the trick did worked but it installed Windows 11 in legacy mode.

Hence I enabled secure boot and properly reinstalled Windows 11 in UEFI mode, then I installed rEFInd which successfully configured Ubuntu and Windows.